# How to make uniform height for table header cells

Tags: html, css

I have a couple table header cells that have wrapped text, which I'm fine with. However, the headers have a background color and it looks awkward having different heights between ones that are single line, and others that are 2 lines (wrapped).

Can I make the headers to be a certain height so the cells containing a single line of text will be the same height as the cells that have 2 lines? I don't want to use no-wrap because I'd like to maintain the table's current width.

When I change the line-height, that makes the spacing increase on the wrapped cells too, so basically the header cells are still different heights.

```
<table class = "large_headers">
    <tr>
       <th>Test1</th>
        <th>Test2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>abc</td>
       <td>def</td>
    </tr>
</table>

.large_headers th{
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `display:table`, `display:table-row` and `display:table-cell`?

Comment: @Oriol I tried them and they don't work. table-row sees to imitate no-wrap and table-cell does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup is invalid. Try this:

```
<table class = "large_headers">
    <tr>
        <th>Test1 foobar foobar</th>
        <th>Test2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>abc</td>
       <td>def</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

With this CSS:

```
.large_headers th{
    background-color:red;
    width:20px;
}
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/wLEu8/

Comment: I can see it clearly works in your fiddle, but it's not working in my code. I hate when this kind of thing happens

Comment: Can you validate your code with the W3C validator? If that fails, please set up a fiddle and we'll sort it.

Comment: I figured it out, but I have some tinkering to do. I'm using CakePHP and using the form helper to generate my headers for pagination. When I remove that and just have text, it then works. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

`th`s should belong in a `tr` like a `td`.

Comment: I do have them, I was too quick to update my post with some code.